# Day to Day tasks for a junior DBA

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if anyone would be able to help by giving me a few scenarios/tasks to complete on SQL Server 2012/16 please?

I am learning SQL Server to move from a desktop role to a junior DBA. I have my own lab at home, but only has adventureworks running on a single SQL instance. I can write basic/intermediate queries with inner joins, aggregates etc. What I'm looking for is some basic DBA tasks to practice with. Unfortunately, the interwebs is full of tutorials on how to write SQL, but I can't find much on then putting it into real life use.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Happy New Year!!

Comment: Duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4836/507

Comment: @ShawnMelton The questions are related, but why do you say this question is a duplicate? The question here is "I wonder if anyone would be able to help by giving me a few scenarios/tasks to complete on SQL Server 2012/16". That is not the question in the post you are referencing.